# 'Head First' Style Data Structures & Algorithms Book?

Tags: c++, data-structures, tree, graph-theory

I loved the Head First series book on object oriented design.  It was a very gentle and funny introduction to the subject.  I am currently taking a data structures class and find the text we are using (Kruse/Ryba Data Structures and Program Design in C++) to be very dry and hard to comprehend.  This is mostly due I think to my own limitations in the area of Mathematics.

Does anyone know of a Data Structures text that is written in a lighter style, with a sense of humor, that still covers all the basics like Binary Trees, B Trees, and Graphs?

Comment: Since it's been some time since you asked the question were you able to find any lighter style text on Data Structures? If so can you let us know about it? Thanks.

Comment: 2 part Algorithms using Java Free course by Bob Sedgewick and Kevin Wayne : https://www.coursera.org/course/algs4partII
Note: Need to wait for the course to be open and register for it.

Course format : There will be two lectures (75 minutes each) each week. The lectures are each broken into about 4-6 segments, separated by interactive quiz questions for you to to help you process and understand the material. In addition, there will be a problem set and a programming assignment each week and there will be a final exam.

Answer (score 26):

The [Algorithm Design Manual](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1848000693) by [Steve Skiena](http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~algorith/) isn't exactly a barrel of laughs, but it's relatively light on the deeper mathematics and contains lots of what he calls "War Stories", which are illustrative examples from real world situations where algorithm work really paid off (or, sometimes, totally failed). He's also got his [audio and video lectures online](http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~algorith/video-lectures/), and he's got a nice lecture style with bits of humor interspersed, so it might be what you are looking for.

Comment: This is a good book, I recommend it.

Comment: I like this book as well, although I find it has less overall content/theory than a dry book like "Introduction to Algorithms" by Carmen, etc.  I enjoyed the tale of the psychic number picker :)

Answer (score 3):

This too is not light either but it is pretty decent

[Algorithms and data structures by Robert Lafore](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1571690956)

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing more readable and meaningful, in my opinion than [http://www.amazon.com/Bundle-Algorithms-Parts-1-5-Fundamentals/dp/020172684X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020172684X)

It's 2 books, part 5 being graphs and is not as useful as the other book - unless of course, you want to use graphs to solve a problem. :)

Comment: But in the end, we all use "trees" to solve problems, which are graph.

Answer (score 1):

[How to Solve it By Computer by Dromey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_to_Solve_It_By_Computer) though not exactly an algorithms book takes the approach of *re-discovering* the process by which many data-structures and algorithms were arrived at over the years. This allows us to understand the flow of thought behind the code and some of the forces at work.

Related: This book follows in the foot-steps of another great book: [How to Solve It by G. Polya](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_to_Solve_It) which talks about how great mathematicians go about the problem-solving process.

Comment: Links:  
[Audio, Video, PPT lectures on Algorithms by Steven Skiena author of Algorithm Design Manual](http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~algorith/video-lectures)  
[Algorist.com by Steven Skiena](http://www.algorist.com)  
[Audio, Video, PPT lectures on Discrete Structures by Steven Skiena](http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~algorith/math-video)  
[Steven Skiena's Algorithm Design Manual Solutions Wiki](http://www2.algorithm.cs.sunysb.edu:8080/mediawiki/index.php/The_Algorithms_Design_Manual_%28Second_Edition%29)  
[Stony Brook Algorithm Repository](http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~algorith)

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using Larry Nyhoff's [ADTs, Data Structures, and Problem Solving with C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131409093).

It's not as light or enjoyable to read as a Head First series book, but it's really well detailed on binary trees, b trees, and graphs. Its code samples have been really helpful for completing my assignments. No higher math knowledge is required to understand the text (except, of course, on the chapter dedicated to algorithm analysis).

Answer (score 0):

[Beginning Algorithms by Harris and Ross](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0764596748) (a Wrox Press book) was one I liked, although its examples are presented in Java, not C++.  Might be a nice accompaniment to the text you're trudging through in class.

Answer (score -2):

I've heard good things about "Introduction to algorithms, A creative approach - Udi Manber"
I can't verify it though since it's not available locally :(

[http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Algorithms-Creative-Udi-Manber/dp/0201120372](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201120372)